# Reshaping error in multivariate normal function with Numpy - Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have this data (c4), I want to use 4-fold cross validation testing on this matrix.
The way that I'm splitting the data is as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import math

c4 = np.array([
[5,10,14,18,22,19,21,18,18,19,19,18,15,15,12,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1],
[6,9,11,12,10,10,13,16,18,21,20,19,8,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[4,8,12,17,18,21,21,21,17,16,15,13,7,8,8,7,7,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,2],
[3,7,12,17,19,20,22,20,20,19,19,18,17,16,16,15,14,13,12,9,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[2,5,8,10,10,11,11,10,13,17,19,20,22,22,20,16,15,15,13,11,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[4,8,10,11,10,15,15,17,18,19,18,20,18,17,15,13,12,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2],
[2,8,12,15,18,20,19,20,21,21,23,19,19,16,16,16,14,12,10,7,7,7,7,6,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[2,13,17,18,21,22,20,18,18,17,17,15,13,11,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,1],
[6,6,9,14,15,18,20,20,22,20,16,16,15,11,8,8,8,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4],
[8,13,16,20,20,20,19,17,17,17,17,15,14,13,10,6,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,2,2],
[5,9,17,18,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,12,11,10,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,3],
[4,6,8,11,16,17,18,20,16,17,16,17,17,16,14,12,12,10,9,9,8,8,6,4,3,3,3,2,2,2] ])

kf = KFold(n_splits=4)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(c4):
    X_train, X_test = c4[train_index], c4[test_index]
    X_train_mean = np.mean(X_train)
    X_train_cov = np.cov(X_train.T)
    v = multivariate_normal(X_train_mean, X_train_cov)
    res = v.pdf(X_test)
    print (res)
```

but it didn't work with me, despite that the splitting loop works well with small sample of data.

The error message that I got:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 900 into shape (1,1)

**Note: the length of all rows is equal.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a remark, please include your imports in the beginning of your code (KFold, multivariate_normal). Also, you could reduce the size of c4 and still have your bug: this would make the example more readable.

Comment: Ok, thanks @P.Camilleri

Comment: You can also reduce the number of features (columns of c4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the mean of entire matrix `X_train` when you do `np.mean(X_train)`. What you should do is take mean across the sample axis i.e. if your features are across columns and different samples are across rows, then replace `np.mean(X_train)` by `np.mean(X_train, axis=0)`. This should solve the error.

Including this line in the above code makes it work. Basically, `np.mean(c4[test_index], axis=0)` will given you a `1 x 30` mean vector instead of a scalar mean.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
v = mvn(np.mean(c4[test_index], axis=0), X_train_cov + np.eye(30))
```

I had to add an identity matrix because I was getting a singular matrix error. However, that has to do with how `c4` is defined and nothing to do with this code. Note that to avoid the singularity, you typically add a very small value on the diagonal and  not an identity matrix. This is just for illustration.

Comment: Have you tried your approach? It does not solve the error.

Comment: I did... it did not give me an error. When I removed `axis=0`, I was able to reproduce the error that OP posted. Let me post a code snippet that works.

Comment: This doesn't solve the error, but I made the change that @P.Camilleri talked about in his post. If I add X_train in the arguments, this error will appear: TypeError: __call__() got multiple values for argument 'cov'
and if I didn't add this argument, this error appears: numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix

Comment: From the same `multivariate_normal` documentation, it is valid to call it without the first argument `x` i.e. just with mean and variance. Read this: << Alternatively, the object may be called (as a function) to fix the mean

and covariance parameters, returning a “frozen” multivariate normal

random variable:

rv = multivariate_normal(mean=None, scale=1)>>. So that may or may not be the solution to your error. However, what I mentioned is most likely an error on your part. Are you sure you want a `30 x 30` covariance matrix and then a `1 x 1` scalar as mean. That does not make sense.

Comment: The data set is from the lecturer of M.L. course, it represents a text recognition values. but the last one with np.eye(30) works with me.

Comment: Adding `np.eye(30)` makes the matrix non-singular. However, you should add a small value such as `1e-3`. In addition, also pay attention as to why the matrix became singular in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What is `multivariate_normal` ? If it is from `scipy.stats`, then per the doc you must do

```
 multivariate_normal.pdf(X_test, np.mean(X_train, axis=0), X_train_cov)
```

[The doc is here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)

Comment: Yup, its from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

Comment: The same thing as you can see, the first argument is mean and the second is covariance.

Comment: No, I think the first argument is the desired quantiles. Read the doc that I pointed you to

Comment: I made this change:  v = multivariate_normal(X_train, X_train_mean, cov=X_train_cov)

But I got this error:
TypeError: __call__() got multiple values for argument 'cov'

Comment: @MeqdadDarweesh see my edit. Make sure that X_train_cov is not singular.

Comment: @MeqdadDarweesh if it does, you can mark my answer as accepted by clicking the validation sign next to it. Appreciate it!